# Is there anything like Meshmixer's “Attract Tool” in Blender?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

In Meshmixer there is a tool called "Attract" where you designate a target mesh and an object mesh. With that tool, the object gets attracted to the target. This is a way to snap one mesh (very irregular and deformed) to another irregular and deformed mesh. Is there anything like this in Blender?

I need to clarify this even further: suppose you have a real object with a hole and want to create a piece, using 3D printing, to fill the hole and fix the object. For example: a plastic bottle with a hole in the lateral surface. Then you scan it to get a mesh into an .stl file. The "hole" in the mesh can be very irregular and the border edges are rounded, so the mesh does not behave as fine as in the built in meshes of Blender. So, I think in designing a piece that have "more or less" the form and shape of the hole and try to accommodate (deform) it to the form and shape of the hole in order to fit "exactly". The problem is that here you work with a mesh comming from an .stl file and the object can be very iregular, so is its hole also. I believe that this can be done in Blender, but... how? How do you create a mesh that fits the missing piece?

Here's a video of the tool in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxTBTMJvUxw

Comment: Did you try the Shrikwrap modifier?

Comment: No, I haven´t. I´m really a newbie in Blender, so I don´t know how it works exactly. But I´ll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a combination of Vertex Weights and a Shrinkwrap modifier.

- On the object to be deformed, in its Data tab, Vertex Groups panel,
  create a vertex group .. call it something like 'Shrinkwrap'
- Assign vertices to it. Vertices can have a weight between 0 and 1 in the group, or not belong to the group at all.
- One approach would be to assign only the vertices you want to deform
  to the group, with weight 0....
- Assign a Shrinkwrap modifier to the object, targeted on the object you want to shrink to,and affecting only the Vertex Group you've created.
- Now in Weight Paint mode, you can hit 'Restrict' in the Tool tab > Options panel to protect vertices outside the Vertex Group from being affected..
- .. and paint weight into the group. As you paint, the vertices will be drawn to the target.

There are numerous options .. in the modifier, and in the way you paint or assign weights to the vertices, (for instance, you can forget painting, and assign weights in Edit Mode) so really, it would be good to have a mooch in the docs and play with them, and if you get stuck and there's a particular way you'd like the tool-combination to behave, come back with a comment, and we can be more specific.